# MacBook Pro with Retina display (Late 2012) not outputting anything above 1080p

Tags: macbook-pro, resolution, display

I know it won't support 4k but it should at least do 1440 right? I can't get higher than 1080p...

[image]

**UPDATE**:
I pressed alt and clicked "scaled" to unlock the extra resolutions as suggested by Buscar웃. It gives me more options but onfortunately still nothing higher than 1080p :(

[image]

This macbook is [quoted](http://support.apple.com/kb/SP658) as supporting "up to 2560 by 1600 pixels on up to two external displays" and it does so with the thunderbolt cinema display. Surely it should be able to do the same with my new 4k monitor? If it matters, the display I'm using is the AOC U2868PQU. I'm not using "mirroring" as suggested by LaX.

Comment: What makes you say it should at least do 1440?

Comment: 1080p - The Resolution is 1920x1080 pixels, sent at 60 complete frames per second. --> Hold alt key before pressing Scaled to see all resolution supported.

Comment: @Buscar웃 I tip my hat to you, the option key shortcut has just brightened my day!

Comment: Lets make that a answer so we can close it as done :)

Comment: @JashJacob http://support.apple.com/kb/SP658 up to 2560 by 1600 pixels on up to two external displays

Answer (score 4):

I managed to get full 3840×2160 @30Hz using mini-displayport cable and an app called [SwitchResX](http://www.madrau.com/). Here are my custom settings, you need to reboot the machine to apply them:

[image]

As a word of warning, this does make things eye-bleedingly small. (Pretty cool though - [full-size](http://www.mattburns.co.uk/blog/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/Screen-Shot-2014-09-30-at-17.17.13.png))

[image]

Personally, I found the ‘scaled’ resolution of 1920×1200 to be the best for me because it uses HiDPI to give you that retina feel you’re used to. It will look like 1920×1200 but actually use more pixels to paint it. Here are the settings:

[image]

This is much more sensible (although I would like it smaller to be honest).
The downside is that you lose some of the screen down the sides. Let me know if you have any better suggestions.

If you find the colours going a bit funny, I used SwitchResX to change the color profile to sRGB IEC61966-2.1 like this:

[image]

For more details, go to my blog post here: http://www.mattburns.co.uk/blog/2014/09/30/running-the-4k-aoc-u2868pqu-and-intel-hd4000-graphics/

Answer (score 3):

1080p - The Resolution is 1920x1080 pixels, sent at 60 complete frames per second.

--> Hold <kbd>alt</kbd> key before pressing Scaled to see all resolution supported.

If you use the "Underscan slider" it will allow you to get higher resolution at the cost of screen refresh rate. The reason we use 50/60 Hz refresh rate is the human eye can not see screen refresh (flickering). But if you are not watching movies ect...then running a 30 Hz will slow down the refresh rate, and give you higher pixel count.

Comment: Good suggestion but it only added lower resolutions... (see updated question)

Comment: Yes, it will show you ALL supported display resolutions that it has found for your monitor.

Answer (score 0):

If your issue is about your TV being 4K and your Mac not allowing you to display higher resolution than 1080p, you have to first make sure you're not using screen mirroring. You have to expand the desktop to use separate resolutions.

Now, if you still don't have the required resolution, you can try using the following script from GitHub: https://github.com/vinc3m1/mac-pixel-clock-patch

It'll remove any limitation your Mac might have about external displays.

Comment: Thanks, but that isn't the problem, I already disabled that.

Comment: @mattburns OK, I edited my answer accordingly. But in short, you can use this: https://github.com/vinc3m1/mac-pixel-clock-patch

Tell me if that helped…